# jQuery .remove() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an script that uses datatables and keytables scripts, and when user clicks in a button I launch a jQuery UI dialog to confirm delete one row of the table. The row is deleted correctly of the database by AJAX and fadeOut of the table, but I don't know why the row is not removed from the DOM. Here is dialog code:

```
$('#delConfDialog').dialog({
                autoOpen : false,

                modal : true,

                beforeClose : function(event, ui) {
                    setTimeout(function() {
                        keys = new KeyTable({
                            "table" : document.getElementById('records'),
                            "datatable" : dataTable,
                            "focus" : tableFocus
                        });
                        keys.fnSetPosition(currentPosition[0], currentPosition[1]);
                        addTableEvents();
                    }, 50);

                },

                buttons : {
                    'Cancelar' : function() {
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                    },

                    'OK' : function() {
                        $('#ajaxLoadAni').fadeIn('fast');
                        $(this).dialog('close');
                        eliminar = elementoEliminar;
                        delHref = eliminar.attr('delete');
                        currentPosition[1] = currentPosition[1] + 1;
                        $.ajax({
                            url : delHref,

                            success : function(response) {
                                $('#ajaxLoadAni').fadeOut('fast');
                                eliminar.fadeOut("fast", function() {
                                    eliminar.remove();
                                });

                            }
                        });

                    }
                }

            });
```

Comment: what is `elementoEliminar` or `eliminar ` is it getting faded out...

Comment: What is elementoEliminar ? is valid in console ?

Comment: elementoEliminar is a global variable that contains the element that I want to delete. It's OK because the script fades out that element, the problem is that the element is not removed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be the use of a global variable

try

```
var eliminar = elementoEliminar;
eliminar.fadeOut("fast", function () {
    eliminar.remove();
});
```